# What data structure to use to easily search for int max value and return relevant object?

Tags: java, oop

There is two classes `Auction` and `Lot`. How to store data: Client (Thread) and Bid (int) in a such way that this data structure can be easily searched by Bid(lot.Max) and returned relevant Client object?

```
public class Lot {

    public HashMap<ClientThread, Integer> mapBids= new HashMap<ClientThread, Integer>();
}

public class Auction {
    List<Lot> lots = new ArrayList<Lot>();
        for(Lot lot: lots){
            int lastBid = lot.BiggestBid;
            ...
              // How to get Client object which has "lot.BiggestBid" ? 
             System.out.println(
                 lot.mapBids.get(lot.BiggestBid).someClientThreadMethod(args)); // wrong 

         }
  }
```

Probably I need in `Lot` a data structure which will hold pair of `Client` and `BiggestBid`, and can be return the `Client` who have `BiggestBid`...

---

The Client and/or BiggestBid can be the same for some entities.

---

Maybe two parallel arrays will work.

Comment: Do you need to keep track of all the bids? If you are able to store the `BiggestBid` in `Lot`, would you not be able to store the `Client` from which this `BiggestBid` came from as well?

Comment: Yes, I can but it this case I cannot be able to display all clients and its' bids made before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bids are unique - use TreeMap. Otherwise, use SortedList. Both Map and List are using natural order if no comparator specified during creation. The biggest and the smallest key retrieval is very efficient O(1). In case you need thread safety - use SynchronizedCollection,

Comment: Do I need to use SynchronizedCollection if I access List using synchronized methods?

Comment: In case you are not holding the references to the same collection and perform mutating operations on the same collection simultaneously, you do not need synchronized collections.

Answer (score 0):

You want something that implements the [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface -- instead of HashMap, use TreeMap?

Comment: What if SortedMap will have duplicated keys Client or Bid?